# Get All Issues on GitHub repository in specific month using GitHub API

Tags: github

I am trying to get all Pull requests created by specific user in a specific month in my django application using GitHub API.

e.g: 
https://api.github.com/repos/myrepo/example/issues?creator=person_name&start_date=2018-1-1&end_date=2018-1-31

Comment: Okay, cool. In what way is the request you show here not working? Please read [ask].

Comment: Hey dear I know that what request I made is not working, it is just to  show what I want, If it was working why I post my question here? Have a look at names used in url they are dummy to show I want something like that.

Comment: I'm not asking _if_ your example is working. I'm asking _how_ it's _not working_. Again, please read [ask].

Comment: it is just a dummy url to show what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find issues created by a user in a given month using the [search issues API endpoint](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-issues), e.g.

```
https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=author:username+created:2018-01-01..2018-01-31
```

`created` [can take a value like `YYYY-MM-DD..YYYY-MM-DD` to set a date range](https://help.github.com/articles/understanding-the-search-syntax/#query-for-dates).

You might also want to add `type:issue` so you don't see pull requests or `repo:user-or-org/repo` to restrict results to a single repository.

Note that there are restrictions on searching users' contributions, including issues. You may need to [have your users authenticate](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/authorizing-oauth-apps/) before you can search their issues. You should be able to try the endpoint out with your own user account, as long as you've got an authenticated session (e.g. by using a search URL in a browser where you're logged into GitHub).

Comment: Thank you for your response, what If instead of getting all issues of a single user I want all issues in a repository in a given month? so how can I change the query? Thank you

Comment: @AwaishKumar, that seems like a small modification to the query described above. In fact, the answer mentions an additional query parameter for searching repositories. Have you tried using that? Have you looked for such a value in the documentation?